# Blinking image issues for javascript timer

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with the timer I created. I just added in a code snippet that will cause a red rectangle to begin flashing(blinking) on the screen between 30 seconds and zero seconds. Once the timer hits zero the blinking needs to stop. The timer should only blink between 30 seconds and 0 seconds. For some reason my blinkRed() function is going haywire and I cannot figure out why. Sometimes it stops when it is supposed to other times it does whatever.

My code is below:

```js
var seconds = 20; //Variables for the code below
var countdownTimer;
var imgBlink;

function showGreen() {
 var imgGreen = document.getElementById('greenGo');
 imgGreen.style.visibility = 'visible';
 };
function hideGreen() {
 var imgGreen = document.getElementById('greenGo');
 imgGreen.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
function showYellow() {
 var imgYellow = document.getElementById('yellowAlmost');
 imgYellow.style.visibility = 'visible';
 };
function hideYellow() {
 var imgYellow = document.getElementById('yellowAlmost');
 imgYellow.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};

function blinkRed(){
var redBlink = document.getElementById('redStop');

    if(redBlink.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        redBlink.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        redBlink.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
imgBlink = setTimeout("blinkRed()", 1000);
};

function showRed() {
 var imgRed = document.getElementById('redStop');
 imgRed.style.visibility = 'visible';
};
function hideRed() {
 var imgRed = document.getElementById('redStop');
 imgRed.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};

function secondPassed(){
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60); //takes the output of seconds/60 and makes rounds it down. 4.7 = 4, 3.7 = 3. (to keep the minutes displaying right)
 var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //takes remainder of seconds/60 and displays it. so 270/60 = 4.5 this displays it as 30 so it becomes 4:30 instead of 4.5
 if (remainingSeconds < 10) {  //if remaining seconds are less than 10 add a zero before the number. Displays numbers like 09 08 07 06
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays time in the html page  5:06
    document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays the time a second time
   if (seconds == 0) {
  clearInterval(countdownTimer);//keeps value at zero once it hits zero. 0:00 will not go anymore
  alert("Time is Up, Try again");
  }
};


function changeColor(){ //this changes the background color based on the time that has elapsed
 if (seconds <= 300 && seconds > 150) {  //green between 5:00 - 1:30
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[0]+")";
  showGreen();
 }
 else if (seconds <= 150 && seconds > 60) { //yellow between 1:30 - 30
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[1]+")";
  hideGreen();
  showYellow();
 }
 else if(seconds <= 60 && seconds > 30){ // red between 30 - 0
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[2]+")";
  hideYellow();
  showRed();
 }
 else if (seconds <= 30 && seconds > 0) {
  hideRed();
  blinkRed();
 }
 else if (seconds == 0){
  clearTimeout(imgBlink);
  }
};
 
function countdown(start){ //code for the button. When button is clicked  countdown() calls on secondPassed() to begin count down.
 secondPassed();
 if (seconds != 0) { //actual code to decrement the time
 seconds --;
 countdownTimer = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
 changeColor();  //calls the changeColor() function so that background changes
 start.disabled = true; //disables the "start" button after being pressed
 }
 if (start.disabled = true){ //if one of the 'start' buttons are pressed both are disabled
 start2.disabled = true;
 }
 //startDisabled2();
};

function cdpause() { //pauses countdown
        // pauses countdown
        clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
  clearTimeout(imgBlink);
};
    
function cdreset() {
        // resets countdown
        cdpause(); //calls on the pause function to prevent from automatically starting after reset
        secondPassed(); //reverts back to original secondPassed() function
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false; //Enables the "start" button that has been disabled from countdown(start) function.
  document.getElementById('start2').disabled = false; //enables the 'start2' button. same as above.
  hideGreen();
  hideYellow();
  hideRed();
};
```

```css
#countdown{
font-size: 2em;
position: inherit;
left: 120px;
top: 5px;
}

#countdown2{
font-size: 2em;
position: inherit;
left: 120px;
top: 30px;
}

#greenGo{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: -1;
}
#yellowAlmost{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: -1;
}
#redStop {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTicket2.0.css">
<script src = "Timer2.js">
</script>
</head>

<<div id = "timerBackground">
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<div id = "timerButtons">
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown(this)" id = "start">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset(seconds = 300)">
</div>
</div>

<div id = "timerBackground2">
<span id="countdown2" class="timer"></span>
<div id = "timerButtons2">
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown(this)" id = "start2">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset(seconds = 300)">
</div>
</div>

<img src = "greenGo.png" id = "greenGo" alt = "greenGo">
<img src = "redStop.png" id = "redStop" alt = "redStop">
<img src = "yellowAlmost.png" id = "yellowAlmost" alt = "yellowAlmost">

</body>
</html>
```

Ive attempted to add clearTimeout(imgBlink); to just about everything I can think of and nothing seems to work. It just keeps ticking away.

Comment: I clicked the "Run code snippet" button above and it looks like it works as you are expecting ? If I am wrong can you explain more?

Comment: same! Try making a jsfiddle and try to reproduce the issue

Comment: The reset button when pressed would restart the blinking animation. I ended up figuring out a few mins ago. I added an if statement to the blinkRed() function and now it works without glitching out (see below). The blinkRed function would continue to run after pressing reset or stop twice. But got it situated, Thank you much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. I added:

```js
imgBlink = setTimeout("blinkRed()", 1000);
 if(seconds == 0){
  clearTimeout(imgBlink);
  }
```

Into the blinkRed() function and now it works like a charm. Although if you press the stop button twice it continues to tick. But that is a minor issue.

Here is the updated javascript.

```js
var seconds = 20; //Variables for the code below
var countdownTimer;
var imgBlink;

/*function startDisabled2() {
 start2.disabled == true;
 if (start2.disabled == true) {
 start.disabled = true;
 }
};*/
function showGreen() {
 var imgGreen = document.getElementById('greenGo');
 imgGreen.style.visibility = 'visible';
 };
function hideGreen() {
 var imgGreen = document.getElementById('greenGo');
 imgGreen.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
function showYellow() {
 var imgYellow = document.getElementById('yellowAlmost');
 imgYellow.style.visibility = 'visible';
 };
function hideYellow() {
 var imgYellow = document.getElementById('yellowAlmost');
 imgYellow.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
function showRed() {
 var imgRed = document.getElementById('redStop');
 imgRed.style.visibility = 'visible';
};
function hideRed() {
 var imgRed = document.getElementById('redStop');
 imgRed.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
function blinkRed(){
var redBlink = document.getElementById('redStop');
    if(redBlink.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        redBlink.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        redBlink.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
imgBlink = setTimeout("blinkRed()", 1000);
 if(seconds == 0){
  clearTimeout(imgBlink);
  }
};
/*function stopBlinkRed() {
clearInterval(imgBlink);
};*/

function secondPassed(){
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60); //takes the output of seconds/60 and makes rounds it down. 4.7 = 4, 3.7 = 3. (to keep the minutes displaying right)
 var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //takes remainder of seconds/60 and displays it. so 270/60 = 4.5 this displays it as 30 so it becomes 4:30 instead of 4.5
 if (remainingSeconds < 10) {  //if remaining seconds are less than 10 add a zero before the number. Displays numbers like 09 08 07 06
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays time in the html page  5:06
    document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays the time a second time
   if (seconds == 0) {
  clearInterval(countdownTimer);//keeps value at zero once it hits zero. 0:00 will not go anymore
  alert("Time is Up, Try again");
  }
};


function changeColor(){ //this changes the background color based on the time that has elapsed
 if (seconds <= 300 && seconds > 150) {  //green between 5:00 - 1:30
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[0]+")";
  showGreen();
 }
 else if (seconds <= 150 && seconds > 60) { //yellow between 1:30 - 30
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[1]+")";
  hideGreen();
  showYellow();
 }
 else if(seconds <= 60 && seconds > 30){ // red between 30 - 0
  //document.body.style.background = "url("+colorChange[2]+")";
  hideYellow();
  showRed();
 }
 else if (seconds <= 30 && seconds > 0) {
  hideRed();
  blinkRed();
 }
 else if (seconds == 0){
  showRed();
  }
};
 
function countdown(start){ //code for the button. When button is clicked  countdown() calls on secondPassed() to begin count down.
 secondPassed();
 if (seconds != 0) { //actual code to decrement the time
 seconds --;
 countdownTimer = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
 changeColor();  //calls the changeColor() function so that background changes
 start.disabled = true; //disables the "start" button after being pressed
 }
 if (start.disabled = true){ //if one of the 'start' buttons are pressed both are disabled
 start2.disabled = true;
 }
 //startDisabled2();
};

function cdpause() { //pauses countdown
        // pauses countdown
        clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
  clearTimeout(imgBlink);
};
    
function cdreset() {
        // resets countdown
        cdpause(); //calls on the pause function to prevent from automatically starting after reset
        secondPassed(); //reverts back to original secondPassed() function
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false; //Enables the "start" button that has been disabled from countdown(start) function.
  document.getElementById('start2').disabled = false; //enables the 'start2' button. same as above.
  hideGreen();
  hideYellow();
  hideRed();
};
```